# How to login the website from Python when the values of " name " on the input field is like data[user][mail] , not using selenium?

Tags: python

Im trying to login by this code.

```
res = opener.open(login_url, data)
res.close()
```

But some cases , I can not login.
These websites which can not be logged in have same "name" value on input field  pattern like this.

```
<input name="data[User][mail]" type="text" size="40" value="testuser@google.com" id="UserMail">
```

*I can easily login if the name's values is like simple "username".

Can anyone know how to login with these type of website ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try to use text `"data[User][mail]"` instead of text `"username"`. For server it is only text, not two dimensional list/array.

Comment: btw. servers can use many different technic to check user (ie. HTTP headers, cookies, IP) and problem can be with something different.